# XSLT FOP: force page break within fo:block

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop, page-break

I'm generating a table with different length strings in one column:

[image: ...]

The page break within an `<fo:block/>` in the *Arbeitsgangbeschreibung*-column makes me probles.
As you can see, the string normaly starts on the same line like the numbers and takes the rows it needs. 
But the string which is after the page break (starting with 'Schleifen Stirnseite Gewinde sauber...') won't start on the same line like the numbers it belongs to. It seems the `<fo:block/>` forces it together within one page. 
But I just want the `<fo:block/>` to break at the end of the page. Which means

> Schleifen Stirnseite Gewinde sauber | -

should stand on the first page. And the rest

> Leisten unter Vorrichtung unterlegen (damit Schraubenkopf frei ist)

should stand on the next page.

There arent any `keep-together`-calls which it could accidentally inherit from.
Thats the `<fo:block/>`:

```
<fo:table-cell border-right="{$Standardrand}">
   <fo:block margin-top="4pt" font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold"margin-left="3pt">
      <xsl:value-of select="beschreibung" />
   </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: One thing I would look into is try to make the height of the contents of the POS and AF columns 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `widows="1"` and `orphans="1"` to the `fo:block`.

`widows` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#widows) and `orphans` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#orphans) set the minimum number of lines of a block of text to be left at the bottom or top of a page, respectively.  The initial value for both is 2, with the result that you can't split a three-line block of text.  By default, the minimum number of lines that can be split is 4.